# a bytes-like object is required, not 'str': typeerror in compressed file

Tags: python-3.x, compression, substring, typeerror

I am finding substring in compressed file  using following python script. I am getting "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'". Please any one help me in fixing this.

```
from re import *
import re
import gzip
import sys
import io
import os

seq={}
with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as  fh:
    for line1 in fh:
            a=line1.split("\t")
            seq[a[0]]=a[1]
            abcd="AGATCGGAAGAGCTCGTATGCCGTCTTCTGCTTG"
            print(a[0],"\t",seq[a[0]])

count={}
with gzip.open(sys.argv[2]) as gz_file:
    with io.BufferedReader(gz_file) as f:
            for line in f:
                    for b in seq:
                            if abcd in line:
                                    count[b] +=1

for c in count:
    print(c,"\t",count[c])

fh.close()
gz_file.close()
f.close()
```

and input files are

TruSeq2_SE      AGATCGGAAGAGCTCGTATGCCGTCTTCTGCTTG

the second file is compressed text file.  The line "if abcd in line:" shows the error.

Comment: Code Formatting tip: Keep an even identation size for your code. Although usign different identation sizes is not a syntax error for the compiler, it is awful for humans. Also consider using always 4 spaces for indentation - it gives a clear view of what is where without eating too much space.

Comment: Also saying in whch line the error is raised should help you get any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "BufferedReader"  class gives you bytestrings, not text strings - you can directly compare both objects in Python3 -

Since these strings just use a few ASCII characters and are not actually text, you can work all the way along with byte strings for your code.

So, whenever you "open"  a file (not gzip.open), open it in binary mode (i.e.
`open(sys.argv[1],'rb')` instead of `'r'` to open the file)

And also prefix your hardcoded string with a `b` so that Python uses a binary string inernally:  `abcd=b"AGATCGGAAGAGCTCGTATGCCGTCTTCTGCTTG"`  - this will avoid a similar error on your `if abcd in line`  - though the error message should be different than the one you presented.

Alternativally, use everything as text - this can give you more methods to work with the strings (Python3's byte strigns are somewhat crippled) presentation of data when printing, and should not be much slower - in that case, instead of the changes suggested above, include an extra line to decode the line fetched from your data-file:

```
with io.BufferedReader(gz_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.decode("latin1")
        for b in seq:
```

(Besides the error, your progam logic seens to be a bit faulty, as you don't actually use a variable string in your innermost comparison - just the fixed  `bcd`  value - but I suppose you can fix taht once you get rid of the errors)